# Apollo client v3 "Cache data may be lost when replacing the field X of a Y object"

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client, react-apollo, apollo-cache-inmemory

I have two simple queries:

```
query GerMenuA {
  menus {
    menuA {
      items {
        label
      }
    }
  }
}

query GerMenuB {
  menus {
    menuB {
      items {
        label
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But in the console I see a warning:

```
Cache data may be lost when replacing the menus field of a Query object.
existing: {"__typename":"Menu","menuA":[{...}]}
incoming: {"__typename":"Menu","menuB":[{...}]}
```

Is there a way just do not merge them and remove the warning? Because if specify in `typePolicies`

```
Menu: { merge: true }
or
Menu: { merge: false }
```

it is not what I want, because these are different data and these two queues do not need to be merged in any way. Also, I don't have an `id` field and `keyFields` will not work for this case, because labels could be the same for both menus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your question is hard to answer without your schema typedefs. But let's suppose it's something like this:

```
type Query {
  menus: Menus
}
type Menus {
  menuA: Menu
  menuB: Menu
}
```

The warning is essentially saying that without any `keyArgs` Apollo Cache has no way to normalize the `menus` Query. Keep in mind from their standpoint- you have a **single** `menus` ***root*** query. (i.e. `GerMenuA` and `GerMenuB` are client side queries not *root* queries).

(Side note- since you don't have `id` fields see [disabling normalization](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-configuration/#disabling-normalization).)

**Option 1: Separate Your Queries**

```
type Query {
  menuA: Menu
  menuB: Menu
}
```

Apollo cache will now store `menuA` and `menuB` as separate queries. If you want to be safe you can set your type policies:

```
const createCache = () => new InMemoryCache({
  typePolicies: {
    Menu: {
      keyFields: false
    },
    Query: {
      fields: {
        menuA: {
          keyArgs: false
        },
        menuB: {
          keyArgs: false
        }
      }
    }
  },
});
```

`keyFields: false` tells AC to store `Menu` under it's parent query. `keyArgs: false` says that both `menuA` and `menuB` are singleton queries. Cache policy will default to `merge: false` so that existing data will be replaced by incoming.

**Option 2: Define Query Parameter**

In this option, you add a `name` parameter to your `menus` query:

```
type Query {
  menus(name: String): Menu
}
```

> By default, the cache stores a separate value for every unique combination of argument values you provide when querying a particular field.

Apollo cache will now store `menus:{name:menuA}` and `menus:{name:menuB}` as separate cache objects. Again, if you want to be safe you can set your type policies:

```
const createCache = () => new InMemoryCache({
  typePolicies: {
    Menu: {
      keyFields: false
    }
  },
});
```

Again, the cache policy will default to `merge: false` so that existing data will be replaced by incoming.

**Option 3: Define Merge Policy**

We've covered why the existing schema is confusing to Apollo Cache. But if you're really set on it, the remaining thing to do is define a merge policy:

```
const createCache = () => new InMemoryCache({
  typePolicies: {
    Menu: {
      keyFields: false
    },
    Menus: {
      keyFields: false,
      merge: true
    },
    Query: {
      fields: {
        menus: {
          keyArgs: false,
          merge: true
        }
      }
    }
  },
});
```

`merge: true` tells Apollo Cache to merge the results of `GerMenuA` and `GerMenuB` into a single `Menus` cache object with both `menuA` and `menuB` properties. Without it each time you ran a query you'd blow away the results of the previous query.